# Ehcache 2 to Ehcache 3 Migration

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache, ehcache-3

We are planning to migrate to ehcache3 from ehcache2 to use offheap memory.

Few Doubts related to the configurations:

1. **diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds** :

Ehcache 2 had a background thread for disk expiry whose timeout can be changed using this config. Is it configurable in 3, If not what is he default value

2. **diskSpoolBufferSizeMB**

Ehcache 2 asynchronously flushes data to disk from memory buffers whose size can be configured.
Is it configurable in 3, If not what is he default value.

Ehcache3 for each cache uses disk segments which is configurable, but what is the buffer size

3. Default thread-pools in Ehcache3

If i don't define disk writer threads, what is the default behavior. Is it fixed/shared/cached ?
Is it recommended to have separate pool for each cache or a common disk writer pool

Feel free to answer partially and give any other recommendation to tune ehcache3 with respect to disk use.

Comment: Hi @Holy_diver, have you found a solution?

Comment: @JiangHongTiao, I have not configured any pools, It is working fine although i can't comment whether it is the best possible config.

Comment: yeah, sure. Thanks for quick response.